# Adding invisible detailview under all cell for uitableview in ios, and making visible/invisible when user tap the cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, detailsview

I have dynamic cells, there are few information on cells. I want to display more information to user  in another detailview but i don't want to switch the another view. I saw this method, adding detailview under all the cells, on another application and I tried to apply that but I did not make it. I need much experience I guess and I think i can gain more knowledge from you guys ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Use following datasource method of `UITableView`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    DirectoryDetails *dDetailVC = [[DirectoryDetails alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dDetailVC animated:YES];\
    // OR [self presentViewController:dDetailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best and most flexible solution is to make custom view for rows (custom class) and use it.

You can create one in Interface Builder, add Identifier to it. Later create class extending UITableViewCell with all properties / methods you need for custom elements there.

You can use it simply in code like that:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"YourIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.detailText = @"detailText";

    return cell;
```

}

To make it visible / invisible prepare function which will change it's visibility and call it on:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    YourCellClass* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell showHideDetails]; //this is details.visibility = !details.visiblity; inside your class
}
```